# is there any way to show jmap dump progress in executing

Tags: java, jmap

Is there any possible way to show jmap dump progress? I am using this command to dump stack:

```
/opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jmap -F -dump:format=b,file=my.dump 5307
```

the output is:

```
[root@log001 ~]# /opt/dabai/tools/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/jmap -F -dump:format=b,file=my.dump 5307
Attaching to process ID 5307, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.211-b12
Dumping heap to my.dump ...
```

stay dump more than 5 minites,how to known what happen in dump progress?should I waiting?